# Can't convert panda series to int? Regular expression is throwing error?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like below

```
  time               a_id      b_id        c_id     d_id  probability
  2015-01-02         237       9712        54       38  [0.194255020142]
  2015-01-02         131        481        60       42   [0.23631604522]
  2015-01-02         277       8842        57       46  [0.176149934661]
  2015-01-02         124       3664        95       48  [0.158623758706]
```

Currently the 'probability' column is of type object. I want to convert it into int, so that I can perform some mathematical operations on it. I used the following code

```
 df_total['probability] = df_total['probability'].astype(int)
```

but it throws me an error which is

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I converted the probability column into a list from a numpy array by subsetting and converting to list. The code for that is given below

```
probability = probs[:,1:]
probability = probability.tolist()
```

What I get back is a list where element is enclosed in a bracket? I don't understand why.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For some reason it looks like you have a list with a single element, this should work: `df_total['probability] = df_total['probability'].apply(lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Thanks Edchum, that worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your current 'probability' column values are each a list with one element?

Try something like:

```
def to_integer(row):
    prob = row['probability'][0] #0th element of the list is the actual float
    return int(prob)
df_total['probability'] = df_total.apply(lambda row: to_integer(row), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the probability is currently in decimal form, converting it to an int will result in the value of zero (e.g. int(.99) results in 0).  In this example, I assume that you'd want the integer value 99 instead. To extract the single value from each list:

```
df['probability'] = [int(100 * i[0]) if i else None for i in df.probability]
```

The `else None` part is in there in case any value is missing.  Trying to index i[0] on None would otherwise throw an error.